# Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

```
:~/Documents/test/education/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app/$ node query.js 
Store path:/home/*******/Documents/test/education/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
2020-02-11T05:56:10.423Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051
Query has completed, checking results
error from query =  Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpc://localhost:7051
    at checkState (/home/******/Documents/test/education/LFS171x/fabric-material/tuna-app/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:883:16) {
  connectFailed: true
}
```

Im experimenting Hyperledger Fabric, using [this link](http://websecuritypatterns.com/blogs/2017/12/15/exploring-hyperledger-fabric-v1-supply-chain-demo-tuna-fish-shipments/) for reference,

Successfully registered admin and user, using registerAdmin.js and registerUser.js.
I am currently facing this error after running **node query.js**.

I need help troubleshooting this error,

> Error: Failed to connect before the deadline
>   URL:grpc://localhost:7051.

Platform: Ubuntu 18.04,
Experimenting hyperledger fabric using Local Environment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `docker ps -a` command, check if the peer is running or not. You can check the peer logs using `docker logs containerid`.